# Javascript Slice: Is is possible to use 2 parameters to select the last character of a string?

Tags: javascript, slice

**The Question**

If I want to use `slice` to get the last character of a string I would do..

```
lastCharacter = theString.slice(-1);
```

Is it possible to select the last character with both a `start` and `end` numerical parameter? Like this..

```
var start = -1;
var end = -0; // nonsensical, I realize
lastCharacter = theString.slice(start, end);
```

**The Answer**

There's no special -0 digit

**The Reason I Asked**

The reason I asked is I was looking to use variables for both parameters which would decrement on each loop as I built a new variable which would be the reverse of `theString`. Until atomrc's answer I didn't think to simply use `theString.length` and work back from the last character rather than using -1 to start with the last character as I do in the example below (which requires an if statement for the first iteration of the for loop).

It was for the third question on codeschools arcade javascript test 'Check if string is a palindrome'

My solution was..

```js
function checkPalindrome(inputString) {
  var characterTotal = inputString.length;
  var inputStringStringified = inputString + '';
  var slicedLetter;
  var sliceStart = -1;
  var sliceEnd = -1;
  var backwards = '';
  for (i = characterTotal; i > 0; i--) {
    if (i === characterTotal) { // first run
      slicedLetter = inputStringStringified.slice(sliceStart);
      sliceStart = sliceStart - 1;
      backwards = backwards + slicedLetter;
    } else {
      slicedLetter = inputStringStringified.slice(sliceStart, sliceEnd);
      sliceStart = sliceStart - 1;
      sliceEnd = sliceEnd - 1;
      backwards = backwards + slicedLetter;
    }
  }
  if (inputString === backwards) {
    alert('true');
  } else {
    alert('false');
  }
}
checkPalindrome('abaaba');
```

I had to create an if statement for the first iteration. With atomrc's answer I see now I didn't have to use negative numbers for slice as I knew the strings length.

With new knowledge my new solution is a bit shorter..

```js
function checkPalindrome(theString) {
  var totalCharacters = theString.length;
  var sliceStart = totalCharacters - 1;
  var sliceEnd = totalCharacters;
  var counter = totalCharacters;
  var backwardsString = '';
  while (counter > 0) {
 var character = theString.slice(sliceStart, sliceEnd);
 sliceStart--;
 sliceEnd--;
 counter--;
 backwardsString = backwardsString + character;
  }
  if (theString === backwardsString) {
 alert('its a palindrome');
  } else {
 alert('its not a palindrome');
  } 
}
checkPalindrome('abaaba');
```

..but still a terrible solution. After solving it I saw what others came up with and some are simple one liners.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There you go :)

```
theString.slice(theString.length - 1, theString.length)
```

Comment: You could mention that the second parameter is not necessary in this case, so it could just be: `theString.slice(theString.length - 1)`

Comment: `lastCharacter = Array.from(theString).reduceRight(c => c)`

Comment: That's true. I am not sure what the author is trying to achieve but he asked for a version with a `start` and `end` parameter (this way everything is explicit and you don't need to know the internals of `slice` to understand what it does ... I guess)

Comment: Thanks, you made me realize I didn't have to work backwards with negative numbers because I already knew the length.